# SparseTensor * Vector

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

How can the following be achieved in tensorflow, when A is a tf.SparseTensor and b is a tf.Variable?

```
A = np.arange(5**2).reshape((5,5))
b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
C = A * b
```

If I try the same notation, I get InvalidArgumentError: Provided indices are out-of-bounds w.r.t. dense side with broadcasted shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` works for *SparseTensor* as well, your problem seems to be with related to the *SparseTensor* itself, you might have provided the indices that are out of the range of the shape you give to it, consider this example:

```
A_t = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,6],[4,4]], values=[3.2,5.1], dense_shape=(5,5))
```

Notice the column index `6` is larger than the shape specified which should have maximum `5` columns, and this gives the same error as you've shown:

```
b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])

B_t = tf.Variable(b, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(A_t * B_t))
```

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Provided indices are
>   out-of-bounds w.r.t. dense side with broadcasted shape

---

Here is a working example:

```
A_t = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,3],[4,4]], values=[3.2,5.1], dense_shape=(5,5)) 

b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
B_t = tf.Variable(b, dtype=tf.float32)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(A_t * B_t))
# SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 3],
#        [4, 4]], dtype=int64), values=array([ 0.       ,  5.0999999], dtype=float32), dense_shape=array([5, 5], dtype=int64))
```